# Rename the footer content in the data file(.csv file) from shell script

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I get a .csv file, in which the last line has the footer value
For Example:

```
896312,3251040212,3251040212,P5,7052016,7072016,0,$0.00,N,1
896312,3251067611,3251067611,P5,7052016,7072016,0,$0.00,N,1
**WOR_FOOTER_20160705100007_000000010_WOR_896312_20160705_100007.csv**--This is footer.
```

I need to replace the footer with `VWOR_FOOTER_20160705100007_000000010_VWOR896312_20160705_100007.csv`

in unix. Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sed -i.bak '$s/WOR/VWOR/g' file
```

should do it.

**Explanation**

- Here `$` picks the last line.
- `s/WOR/VWOR/g` does the global substitution.
- `-i` stands for inplace edit which means directly modify the file. A backup with `.bak` will be auto-created.

---

**Edit**

If your shell doesn't support inplace edit do

```
sed '$s/WOR/VWOR/g' file >tempfile && mv tempfile file
```

**Edit**

If `WOR_FOOTER` is a unique and is guaranteed to appear only in one line then you could do something like below:

```
sed '/WOR_FOOTER/s/WOR/VWOR/g' file >tempfile && mv tempfile file
```

Comment: I am getting this error --> sed: illegal option -- i

Comment: Worked out. Thank you

Comment: @DarshanM : Thankyou for accepting the answer, may I know which version of `sed` you're using and which OS?

Comment: -> The answer is not consistent. Any other alternatives please.

Comment: @DarshanM : For the input you've given, this answer is guaranteed to work fine and is portable too. Could you give me a  sample input for which answer didn't work?

Comment: it works file only if i have a extra line after the footer.

Comment: @DarshanM : That is not correct. The script will change WOR to VWOR provided the line is last Do you expect `WOR` line to appear anywhere in the file?

Comment: @DarshanM : It appears that you're not sure about the file structure. Please see my edit

Comment: @DarshanM : See my edit and please post the sample input with the question.

Comment: @DarshanM : When you post the sample input inside comments all the formatting is lost, kindly update the question with the sample input and mention your problem.

Comment: It worked with this. 
( cat file && echo ) | sed 's/WOR/VWOR/g'

Comment: @DarshanM That solution looks error prone. If that had worked my second solution would certainly work for you. you have [\[ useless use of cat \]](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html). But first of all, instead of putting the file content in the comments please put that in the question itself.  That would be helpful for somebody else in the long run.:) Good luck

Answer (score 1):

sed is the way to go for this as it's a simple substitution on an individual line which is what seds best at but just FYI in portable awk it'd be:

```
awk 'NR>1{print prev} {prev=$0} END{gsub(/WOR/,"VWOR",prev); print prev}'
```

Answer (score -3):

assuming you don't have any other occurence of 'WOR' in the file:

```
sed -i 's/WOR/VWOR/g' <file_name>
```

Comment: This is an error prone solution, You need to filter the last line using `$` option with `sed`